# How do i migrate a Multi site to individual site?

Tags: migration

I have a client who built a site on a sub site of a Multi site network

Can this be migrated to a new domain and independant wordpress site?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can export the content of the site and import it into a new, single-site installation with the [WordPress Importer plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-importer/).

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work but i eventually worked out how to do it and even wrote a tutorial

Comment: In that case, please post an answer explaining what you did so others can learn.

Comment: And (or) post the tutorial money quote here as an answer :)